# how to replace group in php using regex?

Tags: php, regex, tags, preg-replace

i have a string like this:

```
[img]http://placehold.it/350x150[/img] [img]http://placehold.it/350x250[/img]
```

i would like to grab the actual link and place it in a img

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /> <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250" />
```

i could probably create a group with this: `[img](.*)[/img]` but im not sure how to replace it in php.

form another point of view i cold do a simple string replace a few times and replace

```
[img] with <img src=" and [/img] with " />
```

im not sure witch one is the better option

im also trying to do teh same thins for `[video]http://www.youtube.com/watch/?v=lzBxqBsEIlE[/video]`

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Tried to google it? http://www.google.de/search?q=php+bbcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[BBCode Extension for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php)**. This is a solved problem.